# Android positioning views in RelativeLayout

Tags: android, android-layout

I've got following view hierarchy:

[image]

I want ScrollView with nested RelativeLayout to be between relativeHeader and relativeFooter, **because now it's overlapped by footer**. But when I try to add android:layout_above="@id/relativeFooter" I got error that there is no such view. There's probably something funny in what I'm doing. And all that 'nested relativelayouts' stuff. But how can I acomplish my goal?
Here's xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
  xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
  android:layout_width="fill_parent"
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:orientation="vertical">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeHeader"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="60dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal">
    <ImageView
      android:id="@+id/imgMainLogo"
      android:layout_centerVertical="true"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    />
     <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnShort"
      android:text="@string/btnShortRemove_title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    />
  </RelativeLayout>
   <ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/relativeHeader"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">
  <RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    >
    <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tvDetailedTitle"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:textSize="20sp"
    />
    <TextView
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:id="@+id/tvDetailedPrice"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/tvDetailedTitle"
    />
    <TextView
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:id="@+id/tvDetailedPhoneTitle"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="22dp"
       android:layout_below="@id/tvDetailedPrice"
    />
    <TextView
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:id="@+id/tvDetailedPhone"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_below="@id/tvDetailedPhoneTitle"
    />
    <TextView
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:id="@+id/tvDetailedDescriptionTitle"
       android:gravity="center_vertical"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="22dp"
       android:layout_below="@id/tvDetailedPhone"
    />
    <TextView
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
       android:paddingLeft="5dp"
       android:layout_below="@id/tvDetailedDescriptionTitle"
       android:id="@+id/tvDetailedDescription"
       android:text="Description"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     />
     <Gallery 
       android:id="@+id/gallery"
       android:layout_below="@+id/tvDetailedDescription"
       android:layout_width="fill_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:paddingTop="5dp"
     />
 </RelativeLayout>
 </ScrollView>
   <RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeFooter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#716D69"
    >
    <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnDetailedEmail"
      android:text="@string/btnDetailedEmail_title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
      android:width="120dp"
    />
     <Button
      android:id="@+id/btnDetailedCall"
      android:text="@string/btnDetailedCall_title"
      android:layout_width="wrap_content"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
      android:width="120dp"
    />
    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@id/relativeFooter"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:background="#716D69"
    >
```

Remove the "+" from the `android:id="@id/relativeFooter"` like above and do this

```
<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollContent"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/relativeHeader"
    android:layout_above="@+id/relativeFooter"
    android:paddingBottom="5dp">
```

Comment: Thanks, it works! But it looks unusual to me. What's the secret?

Comment: "+" is usually used whenever a new id is being used. In your case the id {relativeFooter} was referenced even before it was declared. Another way of getting it to work is to simply rearrange the layout and place the footer before the scrollview and the layout will still appear the way you want it to..

Comment: Good explanation. You should consider moving this comment into your answer.